# Synchronizing Nao Robots Via Choregraphe

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

Is it possible to synchronize 2 Nao robots without using Python? We want to avoid using python as much as possible, but if its the only way to get them synchronized we will switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In choregraphe, using embedded connection, you can only connect to one robot at a time.
However it's easy to connect to another robot from a box in choregraphe, by typing only two python code line.

Here's an example:
 1. Connect to your NAO as usual, and make a simple program to make it say "hello".
 2. Then we will create another box to ask the other robot to speak, for that: Create an empty box (right click on the central area) then double click on it, to show the code, and on the onStart Method, add this line:

```
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", "ip of the other robot", 9559)
tts.say("hello")
```

And tadaa, both of your robot are speaking, in parallel or sequentially depending how you connect the two boxes...

Comment: How would I connect the boxes to make them speak in synchronization?

Comment: connect box as usual, if you want the robot two speak one at a time, do a sequence of boxes. If you want them to speak at the same moment, connect them in parallel.